# TFS work item rule doesn't work when applying to multiple (Readonly not)

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to apply the (Readonly not) in a work item. So that a certain user can see the work item but cannot edit this, except for the users added in the .xml

I defined it as followed:

```
<Field name="MosCow" refname="company.MosCowID" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <READONLY not="Company\John">
  <READONLY not="Company\Doe">
</Field>
```

Does anyone had experienced the same issue? Or anyone can give me an advice how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a security group in this case. Just create a new group and add your users to it. Then modify your rule to check that group:

`<READONLY not="[Project]\your_group">`

References:

1. [About permissions and groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=vsts)
2. [Apply or ignore rules based on user or group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=tfs-2018#apply-or-ignore-rules-based-on-user-or-group)